# 5 column image on desktop and will become 4 column on mobile Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing on a website right now, and I need help. My website had a content that is having 5 column images for desktop and will become 4 column when it's on mobile. I am bootstrap and here's my code. Thank you.

```
<div class="mainBrands ">          
   <div class="brands">
     <p>BRANDS<p>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class="brandlogo">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <img src="public/images/logo.png">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <img src="public/images/logo.png">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <img src="public/images/logo.png">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <img src="public/images/logo.png">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <img src="public/images/logo.png">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want always 5 img? the grid add up should be 12

Comment: on mobile the 5th image will be gone and will be place on a modal or cordion.

Answer (score 0):

At desktop your screen will be bigger so col-md-2 are applied, bootstrap grid can add up to 12, more than 12 will be in the new row. Therefore in mobile you only seen 4 in a row (4x3 = 12), the 5th will wrap to new row.
Set all of them to 2 will fix it.

Always keep in mind that one row will be divided to 12 col. So you want 5 item, set 1st as `col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1`, other 4 set to `col-xs-2`, that's 11 col, so and another at the end as a placeholder `col-xs-1`

> ## Grid system
>
> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to **12 columns** as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.
>
> REF: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="mainBrands ">
  <div class="brands">
    <p>BRANDS
      <p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="brandlogo">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
      <img src="public/images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="public/images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="public/images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="public/images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="public/images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working on mobile it doesn't change into 4 columns, or can you give me idea how can I work on 5 column images for desktop then when it's on mobile there will be 4 images left then the fifth image will be gone and will be place on a modal. Thank you so much